# Workflow String Builder not passing the answer

Tags: workflow

I have a workflow which has a pretty straightforward formula in the string builder.

It sets a variable to a specificed multiplied by 5 then the next step sets that variable to a column for the current item.

However it doesn't set the column to the answer of the formula, it just sets it to text I've typed out for the formula. So for example if I type the string

```
=5*5
```

instead of giving me 25 it just gives me `=5*5`. Obviously I'm not doing something right, what is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string builder can build only strings.
Use "Do calculation" workflow action to calculate, please see example below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Is there any means in which to do a formula for variable within a workflow? For example if I wanted to TRUNC or ROUNDDOWN?

Comment: Unfortunately out of box it is not possible.